# Elasticsearch: match_phrase_prefix can't find items when search query ends with '0'

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

In my Elastic i'm having this entry: AB-001-123-B

When running a query with match_phrase_prefix like this:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "code": "AB-00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
...
```

I don't get any results.
When changing the code to

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "code": "AB-001"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
...
```

It returns the entry. When removing `-00` from the code it returns the entry as well.

I did several tests with other entries. It seems like he is not able to query when the search-phrase ends with 0.

Why is that? Is there a way to fix this for the query? I tried escaping, without any effects.

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `code` field using the following command `GET index/_mapping/field/code` ?

Comment: The mapping looks like this: {
        "mappings": {
            "code": {
                "full_name": "code",
                "mapping": {
                    "code": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keys": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `code` field is a `text` field analyzed by the `standard` analyzer. This means that `AB-001-123-B` is analyzed into the following tokens:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "AB-001-123-B"
}

Response =>
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "ab",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "001",
      "start_offset" : 3,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "123",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "b",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

The `match_phrase_prefix` is not ideal for your use case. It would be better to query the `code.keys` field using a `prefix` query, like this:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "code.keys": "AB-001"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: Thanks Val! That solved it! About your last comment: I tested it with your solution with upper and lower case. Get the same results in both ways.

Comment: You're right, the normalizer also works at query time, good point! Glad it helped